# LLVM LD option "-rpath-link"

Tags: c, macos, gcc, ld, lld

When using the GNU LD for Linux to link some C code using the "-rpath-link" option it works well and as expected.

However, when using the LLVM LD version 3.7.1 for Mac OS X to link the same C code using the "-rpath-link" option, LD gives an error ("unknown option").

My question is: what is the equivalent of the "-rpath-link" option in the LLVM LD?

Comment: ld.lld is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for ld.bfd, but it does not seem to have anything for rpath-link that I can see in the documentation.  Looks like you'll have to set the the path explicitly.